# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DimocoDigestPayload'

Tags: typescript

Ho do I fix this?

```
    private sortAlphabetically(obj: DimocoDigestPayload): DimocoDigestPayload {
        return Object.keys(obj)
            .sort()
            .reduce(
                (acc: Record<string, unknown>, key: string) => ({
                    ...acc,
                    [key]: obj[key],
                }),
                {},
            ) as DimocoDigestPayload;
    }
```

The whole error message reads like this:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DimocoDigestPayload'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DimocoDigestPayload'.
```

and the `obj[key]` is highlighted.

Comment: @HereticMonkey More or less.